# (Down)vote tooltip gets mixed-up with tags

Tags: bug, tags, design, tooltips

For specifically short questions, I noticed that the downvote tooltip (I guess that there is no short enough question to be affected by the *up*vote tooltip) gets mixed-up with the tags and links under the question. I noticed it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71195940/how-to-push-the-value-of-decorator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193418/transaction-information-from-algoexplorer-io) (before they got closed). Here are screenshots of the second one:

- Dark mode

[image]

- Light mode

[image]

---

- **OS**: Windows 10
- **Browser**: Vivaldi 5.1.2567.49

Comment: Works fine in Firefox Nightly 99.0a1. Strictly speaking, [Vivaldi is not one of the supported browsers](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/289905).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh didn't think about that... Indeed, I can't reproduce in Edge 98... The link you posted states *"If you file a bug report for an unsupported browser and the bug cannot be reproduced in a supported browser, it will not be fixed."* So I guess this can just be deleted?

Comment: Well, _maybe_ it will be fixed if the fix is simple enough; it has [happened before](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/376183/289905).

Comment: Will leave it around in case it gets reproduced on Chrome, Safari or Opera :)

Comment: Technically speaking, the question does not show any Python, nor any blockchain, nor any algorand. So, the tooltip is accidentally correct in this case.

Comment: Can't reproduce on Chrome 95 (or Firefox 97, for that matter). Now we just have to wait for Safari and Opera to respond...

Comment: Looks like whoopsie wednesday came early this week

Comment: Looks like someone forgot a `z-index` for the tooltip - I wonder why would it be only reproducible in Vivaldi, though

Comment: I noticed you have a “Cv-pls” userscript installed. Does it work without any userscripts or other browser extensions?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Another good catch! Disabling Tampermonkey completely made it look as expected... Specifically, it was the Stack Overflow Extras (SOX) script that causes this. Back to wondering if I should delete this...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I mean this meta post has more value than the weekly "Why is it not mandatory to explain downvotes?" post. I would just answer it. It seems like development on the script has stalled so it might be that it will not be fixed at all...

Comment: @Gimby Maybe the people raising those questions have the same problem I presented above and can't see the tooltip of the downvote so they keep asking these meta questions? Just kidding of course, I posted an answer and an issue. Who knows? Might even get fixed...

Comment: This is [now fixed in SOX](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/492#issuecomment-1128304294), sorry for such a late response and for the confusion!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Sebastian](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) pointed out [in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416118/downvote-tooltip-gets-mixed-up-with-tags?noredirect=1#comment895772_416118), I forgot to mention that I have some usescripts running using Tampermonkey. Disabling (or rather, re-enabling) them one-by-one discovered that the culprit for this issue is [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox). After disabling the userscript everything seemed like it should (tooltip in front of everything else).

[I have opened an issue on their GitHub page](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/492).

---

Following the comments under the question, I am now curious if it has anything to do with the specific browser. Would like to hear from anyone else using that script if they can reproduce on any browser.

---

As [Shubham](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3541881/%e1%94%95%e1%96%ba%e1%98%8e%e1%95%8a) [mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416118/downvote-tooltip-gets-mixed-up-with-tags?noredirect=1#comment910119_416118) (and in the GitHub issue), [the issue is now fixed](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/492#issuecomment-1128304294) in version [dev 2.7.14](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js).